# HTTPS Facebook Opengraph URL requested a HTTP redirect, but it could not be followed

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I keep getting this warning in Facebook debug tool for my pages from my site i want to share. URL requested a HTTP redirect, but it could not be followed.

after i re crawl everything usually comes out fine, with description , picture, title etc.

the problem is when someone uses the Facebook share button on the site itself, its hit or miss , sometimes it works fine and shares the post properly, and other times, nothing gets shown, no title, no image, no discription , only url.

I think it has something to do with my site being https

heres an example url https://plugmatch.com/singlepost/312 and i'm getting errors on it, I know that if I rescrape, it'll probably fix it, but thats not the point, I need when users of my site share something, that it gets shared properly.

any ideas

Answer (score 4):

I've run into similar problems and can't say one will solve, but try the following:

- use api v2.9.  (fb recently deprecated an earlier version. I think you are ok with 2.6)
- change your meta property="og:url" to:
  content="   http**s**://plugmatch.com/"

(added 's' to 'http' and an
   '/' at the end of the url)

- Check to make sure your og:url is something that people can access whether they are logged in or not.

Answer (score 0):

Change the OG property `"og:url"` to `"og:url:secure_url"` for https.